# Unit testing $scope.$broadcast inside a function in my controller with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I am unit testing a function in my controller that has a $broadcast event. I am using Jasmine 2.1.3 and visual studios for my test running. I believe I am spying on the $scope.$broadcast correctly but I keep getting this error:

```
Expected spy $broadcast to have been called.
```

I have a controller that has this function inside:

```
    vm.doSomething = function() {
      var things = $scope.things;
      for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
        if(things[i] == true) {
          $scope.$broadcast('isTrue', things[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

In my test file:

```
    beforeEach(function () {

        module('app');

        inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_;
            spyOn($scope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
            myController = $controller('myController',{ $scope: $scope });
        })
    })

    it('should $broadcast event when vm.doSomething is called', function () {
        myController.doSomething();
        $scope.$apply();
        expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I've read many posts and tried all of their solutions but none seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to broadcast on the rootScope

Comment: Is any of the `things` of your `$scope` true? Probably not.

Comment: JB Nizet, you're right! I have some data that was declared up top on the file.  I have another test before this one that also calls vm.doSomething().  In that test, it already massaged the data so that everything returned false in the second call, thus no $broadcast event was called.  THANKS!